# How can I make a creature a Horror?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering whether there is a card that can make a creature a horror in addition to its other types. The card type does not matter. Is there a card like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: [Xenograft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bXenograft%5d) is an enchantment that adds a creature type of your choice to all your creatures. There are also many cards that add *all* creature types to one or more creatures, including the creature cards [Amoeboid Changeling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAmoeboid%20Changeling%5d) and [Mirror Entity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirror%20Entity%5d), and the instants [Blades of Velis Vel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlades%20of%20Velis%20Vel%5d) and [Shields of Velis Vel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShields%20of%20Velis%20Vel%5d).